# Union does not remove duplicate rows in spark data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two data frame like below

```
+--------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
|UniqueFundamentalSet|Taxonomy|FFAction|!||DataPartition|
+--------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
|192730241374        |1       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730241374        |2       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730241373        |1       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730241373        |2       |I|!|       |Japan        |
+--------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+

+--------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
|UniqueFundamentalSet|Taxonomy|FFAction|!||DataPartition|
+--------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
|192730241374        |1       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730241374        |2       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730391384        |1       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730391384        |2       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730241373        |1       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730241373        |2       |I|!|       |Japan        |
+--------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

When i perform union between above data frame i get duplicate rows .
Here is my output

```
+--------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
|UniqueFundamentalSet|Taxonomy|FFAction|!||DataPartition|
+--------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+
|192730241374        |1       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730241374        |2       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730241373        |1       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730241373        |2       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730241374        |1       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730241374        |2       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730391384        |1       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730391384        |2       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730241373        |1       |I|!|       |Japan        |
|192730241373        |2       |I|!|       |Japan        |
+--------------------+--------+-----------+-------------+

val dfToSave = dfMainOutput.union(insertdf)
```

I was in a impression that union removes duplicate rows and unionall keeps it.
I have to use distinct after union .
Can some one please explain this .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your impression was wrong. As stated in [the official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@union(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D):

> Returns a new Dataset containing union of rows in this Dataset and another Dataset>.
>
> This is equivalent to UNION ALL in SQL. To do a SQL-style set union (that does deduplication of elements), use this function followed by a `distinct`.
>
> Also as standard in SQL, this function resolves columns by position (not by name):